# How to auto get data from Form text box using sql queries

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am setting up a Training matrix system for my company, I have three tables one for the employee, one for the certificates that are current and one for entering a record.

I have managed to create forms to insert data to employee and certificate but when trying to create a form for the learning I am hitting a wall.

the learning table only uses int and dates, I'm wanting my form for learning records to be more user-friendly.

currently, I have it working with these form elements

```
certificateid
employeeid
datepassed
dateelapsed
```

I want to add `certificatename` / `employeename` which will be within a query with a LIKE clause. I have tried this but dont get the results I want as I can't get the form boxes to pass the results to the query.

please help or point me in the correct direction.

I have tried creating a variable within the query and then binded this to the variable and added to the form text name but it doesn't seem to take it in.

```
    <?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    // user always
    session_start();
    // Redirect if not logged in
    if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) {
        header('Location: index.html');
        exit();
    }
    //include Header & db Connection
    include ("templates/header.php");
    require ("connect-db.php");

    if(isset($_POST['AddLearn'])){

        //Retrieve the field values from our learning form.
        $CertificateID = !empty($_POST['CertificateID']) ? trim($_POST['CertificateID']) : null;
        $CertificateName = !empty($_POST['CertificateName']) ? trim($_POST['CertificateName']) : null;
        $EmployeeID = !empty($_POST['EmployeeID']) ? trim($_POST['EmployeeID']) : null;
        $Name = !empty($_POST['Name']) ? trim($_POST['Name']) : null;
        $DatePassed = !empty($_POST['DatePassed']) ? trim($_POST['DatePassed']) : null;
        $DateElapsed = !empty($_POST['DateElapsed']) ? trim($_POST['DateElapsed']) : null;

       $sql = "INSERT INTO learning (CertificateID, EmployeeID, DatePassed, DateElapsed) VALUES (:CertificateID, :EmployeeID, :DatePassed, :DateElapsed)";

       $sql2 = "SELECT EmployeeID FROM employee WHERE Name Like '%$Name%' ";

       $sql3 = "SELECT CertificateID FROM certificate WHERE CertificateName LIKE '%$CertificateName%' ";

            $stmt = $dbCon->prepare($sql);
            $stmt2 = $dbCon->prepare($sql2);
            $stmt3 = $dbCon->prepare($sql3);

           //Bind our variables.
            $stmt->bindValue(':CertificateID', $CertificateID);
            $stmt->bindValue(':EmployeeID', $EmployeeID);    
            $stmt->bindValue(':DatePassed', $DatePassed);
            $stmt->bindValue(':DateElapsed', $DateElapsed);

            //secondry binds for stmt2-3

            $stmt2->bindValue(':Name', $Name);

            $stmt3->bindValue(':CertificateName', $CertificateName);

            //Execute the statement
            $result = $stmt->execute();
            $result2 = $stmt2->execute();
            $result3 = $stmt3->execute();



        //If the process is successful.
        if($result){

          echo  'Record Added';
       }else
       {
           echo 'No record was added due to mistakes';
       }
    }

    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>Add New Learning Record</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="adding">
            <h1>Add New learning Record</h1><br>
                 <form action="newlearn.php" method="post">

                <label for="CertificateID">Certificate ID</label>
                <input type="text" id="CertificateID" name="CertificateID"><br>

                <label for="CertificateName">Certificate Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="CertificateNameID" name="CertificateNameID"><br>

                <label for="EmployeeID">Employee ID</label>
                <input type="text" id="EmployeeID" name="EmployeeID"><br>

                <label for="Name">Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="NameID" name="NameID"><br>

                <label for="DatePassed">Date Passed</label><center>(Date in YYYY.MM.DD)</center>
                <input type="text" id="DatePassed" name="DatePassed"><br>

                <label for="DateElapsed">Date Elapsed</label><center>(Date in YYYY.MM.DD)</center>
                <input type="text" id="DateElapsed" name="DateElapsed"><br>

                <input type="submit" name="AddLearn" value="Add New Record"></button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </html>
```

I am expecting the Employee id and the certificate id to be generated using the like clause by scraping the data from the two relevant tables.

[This is my form. i want to be able to enter name and certificate name and it automatically input the id's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeTn2.png)

[Code Error shown in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfvkW.png)

[Code for form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ltoa.png)

[PHP code for the variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkZI2.png)

Comment: Could it be that you are creating the two variables inside the `if(isset($_POST['AddLearn'])){` condition? If so, they will only be filled after you saved a learning to the database. You'll have to move the statements so that they are executed independent of the INSERT-statement.

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues with your code that we'll have to look into:

### Bind Variables

I'll just pick one of the SQL queries but same applies to the rest of them:

```
$sql2 = "SELECT EmployeeID FROM employee WHERE Name Like '%$Name%' ";
// ...
$stmt2->bindValue(':Name', $Name);
```

[Named placeholders](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) should be in the form of: `:Name` so your query should look like this (the wildcard operator makes it a bit less intuitive):

```
$sql2 = "SELECT EmployeeID FROM employee WHERE Name Like CONCAT('%', :Name, '%')";
```

### Not fetching from the SELECT statements

```
$sql2 = "SELECT EmployeeID FROM employee WHERE Name Like LIKE CONCAT('%', :Name, '%')";
$stmt2->bindValue(':Name', $Name);
$result2 = $stmt2->execute();
```

You execute the statement but don't use the result anywhere in your code. Instead you would fetch a single row and show it somewhere in your form:

```
if ($stmt2->rowCount() > 0) {
  $row= $stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  $employeeId= $row['EmployeeID'];
}
```

### Using NULLs for defaults

Also just to point it out on one example row:

```
$DatePassed = !empty($_POST['DatePassed']) ? trim($_POST['DatePassed']) : null;
// ...
$sql = "INSERT INTO learning (CertificateID, EmployeeID, DatePassed, DateElapsed) VALUES (:CertificateID, :EmployeeID, :DatePassed, :DateElapsed)";
$stmt = $dbCon->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(':DatePassed', $DatePassed);
$result = $stmt->execute();
```

In case your database table "learning" allows inserting NULLs in the fields you may create many faulty rows that contain NULL values in fields like "CertificateID", "EmployeeID" and so on. 
Instead I would recommend to:

1. Check fields for completeness on the client-side
2. "Return early": instead of trying to insert a record which will most likely fail if mandatory fields are missing, introduce a field check on the server-side as well. Something like:

```
if (empty($_POST['CertificateID'] || empty($_POST['EmployeeID']) || empty($_POST['DatePassed'])) {
  print "Mandatory fields are missing. Please try again.";
} else {
  // continue with inserting data.
}
```

### Using LIKE instead of checking for equality

I also wonder why you would need to use a LIKE-clause instead of checking for equality? Instead of having the user manually enter the employee name, create a SELECT holding the employee names and then use `WHERE Name = :Name`. This is way more user friendly.

### Update 1:

Your form currently has redundant - better said error-prone - fields: certificate ID and name / employee ID and name. If someone entered a certificate ID that does not fit the certificate name, you'd have incorrect data in your database. Instead as talked about in the comments you would use select lists.

First, load the required data for your SELECTs:

```
$sqlEmployees = "SELECT EmployeeID, Name FROM employee ORDER BY name";
$stmtEmployees = $dbCon->prepare($sql2);
$arrEmployees= array();
if ($stmtEmployees->execute()) {
  $arrEmployees = $stmtEmployees->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

$sqlCertificates = "SELECT CertificateID, CertificateName FROM certificate ORDER BY CertificateName";
$stmtCertificates = $dbCon->prepare($sql2);
$arrCertificates= array();
if ($stmtCertificates->execute()) {
  $arrCertificates = $stmtCertificates->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

Then, output the values as part of your form while getting rid of the redundant fields:

```
<form action="newlearn.php" method="post">

    <label for="CertificateID">Certificate</label>
    <select name="CertificateID" id="CertificateID">
    <?php
      for($i=0;$i<count($arrCertificates);$i++) {
         $row= $arrCertificates[$i];
      ?>
      <option value="<?= $row['CertificateID'] ?>"><?= $row['CertificateName'] ?></option>
      <?php
      }
    ?>
    </select>

    <label for="EmployeeID">Employee</label>
    <select name="EmployeeID" id="EmployeeID">
    <?php
      for($i=0;$i<count($arrEmployees);$i++) {
         $row= $arrEmployees[$i];
      ?>
      <option value="<?= $row['EmployeeID'] ?>"><?= $row['Name'] ?></option>
      <?php
      }
    ?>
    </select>

    <label for="DatePassed">Date Passed</label><center>(Date in YYYY.MM.DD)</center>
    <input type="text" id="DatePassed" name="DatePassed"><br>

    <label for="DateElapsed">Date Elapsed</label><center>(Date in YYYY.MM.DD)</center>
    <input type="text" id="DateElapsed" name="DateElapsed"><br>

    <input type="submit" name="AddLearn" value="Add New Record"></button>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi SaschaM78, thank you for all your helpful advice. i wasnt sure if it would need to be a $ or : but have now altered that. i have also changed it from a like clause to a where =. the original issue i am having is getting the Name box to auto fill the employee id and certificateID for the certificaeName live before submission because i want to make it more user friendly

Comment: Hi @MichaelBroderick and you are welcome. Main problem currently is that `$stmt2` and `$stmt3` will only be executed in case you just have POST'ed data (meaning you just tried to save data). You therefor would need to change your code to fetch the data before the learning is submitted.

Comment: i have recently started and i have not a clue on how to do this. i thought about changing the learning record page to have a drop-down with all names in it and then add the form using variable created from the drop down box but i am unsure. Dont know where to turn or what to even search. any help would be apprecisted

Comment: @MichaelBroderick I've been there a long time ago but I remember how clueless I was myself. I would recommend to: 1.) Load the list of employees and build a dropdown with it 2.) same for Certifications. Then use these as a base for your form. I would also recommend to always use the database-internal IDs to retrieve data instead of using text-based WHERE-clauses which will be slower. Your SELECT lists therefor should have the IDs as their values and the names as the option's content. Then use the IDs to query the database. Good luck!

Comment: i take it by database-internal ID you mean EmployeeID and CertificateID

Comment: @MichaelBroderick exactly!

Comment: its just that when i have the list how to link the ids to the names. should i use SELECT Names, EmployeeID From Employee; for the list echoing that to the dropdown list. then use the id in another dropdown and the. repeat for certificate. how do i link the two field to change with each other.

Comment: @MichaelBroderick I added an update to my answer with an option how to restructure the form. Check if that's helpful for you.

Comment: thanks again @SaschaM78  you sir are a big help. had a headache for a few days over this. i will try it first thing tomorrow. i will let you know how it goes. :-)

Comment: @Dharman thanks for the info, I haven't used PHP for a longer while now. Could you let me know where you found the unnecessary quote in my code? Or do you mean to just remove the single quotes altogether (as per PHP documentation). And just to ask, how would one best write a LIKE-query with bound parameters?

Comment: @MichaelBroderick you are welcome and all the best for getting to know PHP better :-)

Comment: @Dharman thanks, I'll update the answer accordingly. Also thanks for the link but in it there is no mention of the "%" wildcard operator. As far as I've read it needs to be added manually, either as part of the variable bound to the parameter (`$stmt->bindParam(':Name', '%'.$name.'%');`) or in the query itself (`WHERE name LIKE CONCAT('%', :name, '%')`), right? Or is there another way?

Comment: I am getting a weird error with undefined variables, i noticed in your reply there was $sql2 which i changed to $sqlEmployees & $sqlCertificates respectivly. the error i am recieving i will put screenshots within my main post.

Comment: @SaschaM78 to answer your (now deleted) meta question, [removal is perfectly fine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/332043)

Comment: @Zoe thanks for your comment. After rephrasing my search I found a discussion with the same topic, that's why I removed the question. Can't say that I'm OK with it, though, but I guess I'll just have to accept it.